# Is there a command line application that can prettify text containing HTML + CSS + JS?

Tags: command-line, text-formatting

I work on Geany because it is lightweight and simple. But one future I really miss from using sophisticated and heavy code editors is prettifying the code with a keystroke. But Geany allows external scripts to run on the text in the editor through "custom commands".

So I am on the look out for CLI program that can prettify a webpage containing HTML + CSS + JS? Not just HTML or JS. Prettify the webpage if it contains either HTML or CSS or JS or all of them.

Comment: Run it through html-tidy + js-beautify? ( https://github.com/beautify-web/js-beautify )?

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov html-tidy nukes CSS. Besides I am looking for a single utility that can prettify if it's a HTML or CSS or JS.

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen anything for that ever. Including JS/CSS in your HTML code is a bad practice anyways, so if I were you I'd split HTML files into HTML and JS/CSS and pure HTML.

Comment: Of course @ArtemS.Tashkinov. But sometimes one needs to included a little bit of JS into the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First install [prettier](https://prettier.io/) "globally" using either [npm](https://github.com/npm/cli) or your [Package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager).

Using `npm`:

```
npm install -g prettier
```

**To "prettify" CSS using "custom commands" with Geany:**

Config - One time only!

1. `Edit -> Format -> Send selection to -> Set custom commands`
2. Click `Add`
3. Enter `prettier --stdin-filepath temp.css` in Command field.
4. Enter `CSS` in Label
5. Click `OK`.

Now every time you want to "prettify" CSS:

1. Select the CSS text you want to prettify:
2. Go to / press`Edit -> Format -> Send selection to -> CSS`

**[recommended] To "prettify" [any source code file](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html) directly using prettier:**

1. npx prettier --write .
2. Read the "[Usage](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html)" section in the document for more information.

**Caution**: Prettifying, Beautifying or Formatting your source code files **modifies** them.